# Transferring "Money" between accountID in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a question which I have tried to Google but haven't find an answer to yet. What I am trying to do is transferring money between two accounts in MySQL with a stored procedure.  If I for example use Call transfer (20,'Test',3,5). Then I will transfer 20 dollars from accountID 3 to accountID 5 and write the message "Test" , which is what it should do.

At the moment it is however possible to send money between non-existing accounts and the amount can be <0 for the sending accountID, for example call transfer (20000000,'Test',34,54).

Does anyone know how I can solve these problems(amount has to be >=0 and only existing accountIDs can receive and send money)? The code I am using can be found below:

Creating the tables:

```
Create table Account 
(
AccountID int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key 
,amount decimal check (amount >= 0));

Create table Transfers 
(
TransfersID int AUTO_INCREMENT primary key
,amount decimal
,from_account_id int not null
,to_account_id int not null
,note varchar(50) not null
,datetime datetime not null
,Constraint from_account_key foreign key (from_account_id) references 
Accounts (id)
,Constraint to_account_key foreign key (to_account_id) references Accounts 
(id)
);

insert into accounts (id, amount) values (1, (rand()*100));
insert into accounts (id, amount) values (2, (rand()*100));
```

Creating the stored procedure:

```
delimiter //
create procedure transfer (amount int, note varchar(50), sending_account 
int, receiving_account int)
begin

start transaction;
update accounts as A
set A.amount = A.amount - amount
where A.AccountID = sending_account;

update accounts as A
set A.amount = A.amount + amount
where A.AccountID = receiving_account;

insert into transfers values 
(TransfersID, amount, sending_account, receiving_account, note, now());
commit work;

end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Add some range checking to your PHP code

Comment: MySQL does not support `check (amount >= 0)` you can simulate this by using a trigger..

Comment: First of all, you should make the insert into your Transfers table first - both from_account_key and to_account_key in that table are set up as foreign keys referring the Account table, so any attempt at inserting a non-existing id into either of those will fail. In that case, you'll want to rollback the whole thing.

Comment: @CBroe Do you mean that I should write .... Start Transaction; insert into transfers values (TransfersID, amount, sending_account, receiving_account, note, now());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a check for the amount at the beginning of the procedure, and moved `insert into transfers` before `update` statements. There are foreign keys in `transfers` table referencing `account` table, so if you try to insert `id` that does not exist it will fail immediately.

```
delimiter //
create procedure transfer (amount int, note varchar(50), sending_account 
int, receiving_account int)
this_proc:begin 

start transaction;

if amount <= 0 then
    leave this_proc;
end if;

insert into Transfers values 
(TransfersID, amount, sending_account, receiving_account, note, now());

update Account as A
set A.amount = A.amount - amount
where A.AccountID = sending_account;

update Account as A
set A.amount = A.amount + amount
where A.AccountID = receiving_account;

commit work;

end //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: This might be a stupid question but will, 

if amount <= 0 then leave this_proc; end if;

work on the amount column in the account table as well? Obviously you shouldn't be allowed to transfer a negative sum but will the IF-statement also demand that "set A.amount(New amount) = A.amount(Existing amount) - amount(transferred amount)" >=0

Comment: @Spyro It won't, you need an additional check for this: `if not exists (select 1 from Account A where A.AccountID = sending_account and A.amount > amount) then leave this_proc;`

Comment: What does 1 in the select statement mean? I am assuming that I should place the "if exists"-statement before the "insert into Transfers" -statement

Comment: @Spyro Correct. Regarding `select 1`, that is just a way to avoid selecting anything useful (and expensive) from the table, it is often used with a query that just checks for the existence of certain record. You could use `select *` as well, but this is a bit faster.

Comment: I haven't been able to run the question yet, but as soon as I have and it works as I want to I will

Comment: @Spyro OK. Note that you created table named `Account`, but foreign key in `Transfers ` references `Accounts` (plural). You are also trying to insert into `accounts`, but that is not a correct table name.